# Protractor: Checking data is sorted by date

Tags: javascript, angularjs, testing, protractor, end-to-end

I need to check the data returned is sorted by date.  This is how I'm writing it:

```
it('should be sorted by date', function() {
    element.all(by.repeater('users in group.users')).then(
        function(users) {
            var lastUser = users[0].element(by.id('birth-date')).getText();
            for (var i = 1; i < users.length; ++i) {
                var currentUser = users[i].element(by.id('birth-date')).getText();
                expect(moment(currentApplication).format('MMM d, YYYY HH:mm')).toBeGreaterThan(moment(lastApplication).format('MMM d, YYYY HH:mm'));
                lastUser = currentUser;
            }
        }
    )
})
```

This returns:

```
Expected 'Jan 1, 2015 00:00' to be greater than 'Jan 1, 2015 00:00'.
```

What am I doing wrong?  currentUser and lastUser seem to be objects instead of text...but I'm not sure why.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Get the list of all birth dates using [`map()`](http://angular.github.io/protractor/#/api?view=ElementArrayFinder.prototype.map), convert the list of strings to the list of dates and compare with a sorted version of the same array:

```
element.all(by.id('birth-date')).map(function (elm) {
    return elm.getText().then(function (text) {
        return new Date(text);
    });
}).then(function (birthDates) {
    // get a copy of the array and sort it by date (reversed)
    var sortedBirthDates = birthDates.slice();
    sortedBirthDates = sortedBirthDates.sort(function(date1, date2) {
        return date2.getTime() - date1.getTime()
    });

    expect(birthDates).toEqual(sortedBirthDates);
});
```

Comment: I'm getting this: TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'all'

Comment: @Jason oops, typo, fixed :)

Comment: Thanks.  I'm new, so syntax is important for me :)  One more, getting this now: TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'sort'

Comment: Also, is there a reverse sort?

Comment: @Jason yup, `reverse()`. Could you print out the value of `birthDates` before the `expect` line? thanks.

Comment: Using the selenium server at http://localhost:4444/wd/hub
[launcher] Running 1 instances of WebDriver
{ then: [Function: then],
  cancel: [Function: cancel],
  isPending: [Function: isPending] }
F.

Comment: Almost, but not quite.  No more errors, but .reverse() returns no failures, AND .sort() also returns no failures.  One of these should fail :)

Comment: @Jason what is the value of `birthDates` before the `expect()` call?

Comment: I think this is my bug.  It's all showing 'Invalid Date'.  I think my format is odd.  I'm using 'Sep 30, 2014 10:45'

Comment: OMG! I tried to sort my array by standard protractors methods and it was sooooooo awful! Thank you very much.=)

Answer (score 2):

I maked a small research of this topic. My code is:

```
element.all(by.id('birth-date')).map(function (elm) {
    return elm.getText();
}).then(function (birthDates) {
                var sortedbirthDates = birthDates.slice();                                                  
                sortedbirthDates = sortedbirthDates.sort(function compareNumbers(a, b) {                    
                                                              if (a > b) {
                                                                    return 1;
                                                              } });
        expect(birthDates).toEqual(sortedbirthDates);                                                        
    });
```

Here we independent of value type. We can use it for number, string and date.

Answer (score 0):

```
TS:
1) strArr = (elems) => elems.map(async elem => await elem.getText());
2) strToNum = (strArr) => strArr.map(Date.parse);
3) const ordering = {
      isASC: (data: number[]) => data.every((item, i, arr) => !i || arr[i-1] <= item),
      isDESC: (data: number[]) => data.every((item, i, arr) => !i || arr[i-1] >= item)
    }
OR
const ordering = {
      isASC: (data: number[]) => data.slice(1).every((item, i) => data[i] <= item),
      isDESC: (data: number[]) => data.slice(1).every((item, i) => data[i] >= item)
}
```